Most memory efficient way to pass a large list of strings from Python to C++ with pybind11
Pretty much as in the title, I have a large list of strings that I construct in Python, and I want to pass it through pybind11 to C++ to do some processing on it (in a const way, the list of strings is guaranteed to not be changed by the processing). What is the most memory efficient way to do so? Ideally, I'd like to avoid a memory copy if possible, and let Python own the memory for the object.

Leave it as Python list (py::list). Only convert the list elements as you iterate over it (one at a time).... to a std::string_view, I suppose.
